# How to resolve Play framework routing conflicts programmatically

Tags: java, playframework, routes

I have two routes defined in my application viz.

```
GET /resource/:resourceid  ResourceController.getResourceById(resourceid : String)
GET /resource/system       SystemResourceController.getAllSystemResources()
```

The above routes conflict with each other.

I cannot access getAllSystemResources() defined in SystemResourceController.

All the HTTP GET request to the /resource/system. routes to /resource/:resourceid

From the Play-framework documentation at the below link
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/routes

I found that the routes priority is based on the order of route mentioned in the routes file.

Is there anyway I can resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 2):

Change the order. Put the rule for /resource/system before the other one